# Pass a variable from HTML Page to Form-Modal

Tags: javascript, html, angular, modal-dialog, servicenow

I am trying to pass a variable from a table to Form-Modal, hence need a little guidance on snippet. Please refer to the HTLML section.
I need to pass `{{rec.sys_id}}` into a method as a parameter, which is inside this form-modal:

```
"myController.displayUserRecord(<rec.sys_id>)"
```

Please let me know about the approach.
Thank you.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="rec in myController.userRecord">
     <td><a ng-href="" target="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formUserRecord">Click Here</a></td>
     <td>{{rec.sys_id}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>


 <div  class="modal fade" id="formUserRecord" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <p>Check your Workday Record:</p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="myController.displayUserRecord(<rec.sys_id>)">Click here </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myController.displayUserRecord(rec.sys_id)
```